# Can't install drivers for Windows XP. Program too big to fit in memory

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers

**SOLUTION**: Download the driver on other computer. Rename it from .EXE to .zip extension. Copy over the driver via USB to the Dell. Run the setup.exe inside the archive.

Installed fresh **Windows XP** on **Dell** workstation. Downloaded drivers for a specific service tag using another computer onto a USB. Plug the USB into the **Dell** and can't execute any of the drivers. When I click on the drivers a **cmd** window blinks really fast but nothing happens.

What is the problem? I downloaded drivers for appropriate Windows version for the **Dell** computer. There was only one option for drivers filtering: "Windows XP"

What driver executables look like on Dell:

[image]

**EDIT**: Copying the driver executables off USB to the computer didn't fix the problem.

**EDIT2**: The downloaded drivers are **NOT** corrupted. They execute on the other machine. I ran the driver on Dell via cmd and got the following message: "Program is too big to fit in memory"

Comment: Copy those file off the USB to the computer you want to install them on, then run them. They typically extract to a `Dell` folder, then the installer will start.

Comment: It looks like they didn't download correctly

Comment: These are mostly self-extracting archives, you may try to extract them manually with 7zip. Then execute `setup.exe`(or similar) or manually select `.inf` files with `devmgmt.msc` for appropriate device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your **cmd** and execute the mentioned driver file , you should be able to see the error.