# Can't install 7zip on Win XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I want to install 7zip on Windows XP SP3 computer.
But I can't because it gives me the following message: "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

I tried both 32 and 64 bit. Also tried WinRaR and WinZip but get the same error.

EDIT: I got both msi and exe. MSI gives the error, and exe gives "Program is too big to fit in memory" error. I can't add comments for some reason. It just sends me to top of the page, by the way.

EDIT2: I enabled MS Installer service. Didn't help. Same error with msi and exe installers.

EDIT3: The computer has(Dimension e520) 1GB of RAM. Can't tell how much RAM it's using because it shows PF Usage instead of RAM usage in the Task Manager.

EDIT4: I can run regedit.exe

Comment: are you downloading EXE files or MSI files?

Comment: Why would you try a 64-bit installer on a 32-bit Windows installation. Are you sure your downloading a 32-bit installer? Because my 32-bit Windows XP SP3 virtual machine had no problem installing the current release of 7-zip, WinRar, or Winzip.

Comment: is the MS installer service running? you can leave comments after you have a few points of reputation.

Comment: Have you checked the amount of RAM the computer has vs. how much it's currently using?  How old is the computer?  It could be a problem with the memory itself as opposed to a lack of.  It could also be the product of a buggy, old Windows install.

Comment: [Duplicite question](http://superuser.com/questions/677465/cant-install-drivers-for-windows-xp-program-too-big-to-fit-in-memory) Can you execute any exe file, try running `regedit.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to install 7zip on Windows XP SP3 computer. But I can't because it gives me the following message: "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."
>
> I tried both 32 and 64 bit. Also tried WinRaR and WinZip but get the same error.

The installer is corrupt/damaged/incomplete.

> EDIT: I got both msi and exe. MSI gives the error, and exe gives "Program is too big to fit in memory" error.

Your disk is full. Check the drive where your temporary directory (`%temp`) is located. When the installer tries to run, it extracts some files, but it does not have enough space. Alternately, check the drive where your browser cache is located, because it could be out of space, so when you download the installer, it is not complete.

Clear the browser cache, close the browser, free up some space, then download the file again. (Make sure to clear the browser cache first so that you don’t just get the same broken file.)

> EDIT2: I enabled MS Installer service. Didn't help. Same error with msi and exe installers.

Also, open the installer(s) in WinRAR or WinZip and do an archive-test to check if your installer is okay; it should work for both the `.exe` and `.msi` files.